# How to turn off automatic parsing of escaped unicode character in Python 3 json module?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, unicode

I have the following question for ***Python 3.6.5***. There is a string, which contains an escaped unicode character (which is `&`), but the *json* module parses it, and returns a not-escaped unicode character, which is wrong.

How can I turn this off? According to the documentation the encoding flag is deprecated. Here is a minimal code to replicate the issue:

```
import json

example=r"""
{
    "command": "python -m spacy download en \u0026\u0026 python -m spacy download de \u0026\u0026 python main.py"
}
"""
json_example=json.loads(example)
json.dumps(json_example)
```

The last line returns

> ```
> '{"command": "python -m spacy download en && python -m spacy
>  download de && python main.py"}'
> ```

, which I would rather avoid, and keep the **`\u0026`** .

Comment: Okay, and *why* is it wrong?

Comment: Because we manipulate a big json file and we want that key-value pair remains intact.

Comment: I don't understand. "\u0026" == "&". You could have typed "&" in your `example` and it would be the same string. You don't have escaped unicode code points in `example`, you have unicode code points. There is no way to know whether you typed in "\u0026" or "&" by looking at the result.

Comment: Ok, then I ask in a different way, I have a file (escaped_unicode.txt) with the following contents: `{
    "command": "python -m spacy download en \u0026\u0026 python -m spacy download de \u0026\u0026 python main.py"
}` Then I call the following code `import json

with open('escaped_unicode.txt', 'r') as f1:
    json_example = json.load(f1)
    
with open('not_escaped_unicode.txt', 'w') as f2:
    json.dump(json_example, f2, indent=4 * ' ')` and the two files will be different.

Comment: Your example is slightly flawed in that the escape sequences are getting converted to regular ampersands directly in the string literal `example`, not by `json.loads`. But you're also correct that `json` will parse them if you avoided that problem (e.g. by using a raw string literal, `r"""..."""`).

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght I have edited the question based on your feedback.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do what you want. The JSON specification says that a `\uNNNN` sequence in a string is equivalent to the Unicode codepoint the hex digits correspond to. Python's `json` module thus decodes `\u0026` into `&` when it parses the JSON string. There doesn't appear to be any way to turn that off. Once the parsing has happened, there's no easy way to go back, since there's no way for the dumping code to tell that `"&"` should be written with an escape sequence. As far as I can tell, `json.dumps` will never use a `\uNNNN` escape sequences for an ASCII character.

Comment: You cannot turn it off, because the conversion is required by the standard. What you can do is convert it *back, manually* - e.g. by `.replace('&', '\\u0026')` for a single case (notice the double backslash.

Comment: This is kind of "how do I get my JSON parser to stop parsing my JSON".

Comment: @JanosBinder, what is your actual use case? Python and JSON are behaving according to specs. Also \uNNNN don't exactly mean the same thing in Python and JSON. It would be helpful to understand what you need to achieve, and why what appears to be correct Python and JSON does not meet your usage requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a good idea (see the comments under your question), but here is what you could try to do to achieve what you want to: Provide

1. a custom decoder that mangles your escaped sequences before decoding and
2. a custom encoder that reverts the mangling after encoding.

Here is a version that mangles the escape sequences by escaping them once more. It works for your specific example but will break for many others (see the comments under this answer, as well) – which brings me back to the first sentence (Not sure if this is a good idea …).

```py
import json
import re

class EscapeDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    
    def decode(self, s):
        s = re.sub(r"\\u([0-9a-f]{4})", r"\\\\u\1", s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        return super().decode(s)

class EscapeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        
    def encode(self, o):
        s = super().encode(o)
        return re.sub(r"\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})", r"\\u\1", s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

example=r"""
{
    "command": "python -m spacy download en \u0026\u0026 python -m spacy download de \u0026\u0026 python main.py"
}
"""

json_example=json.loads(example, cls=EscapeDecoder)
dumped = json.dumps(json_example, cls=EscapeEncoder, indent=4)
assert(example[1:-1] == dumped)  # strip leading and trailing line break for assertion to work
```

And here is version that is a bit more robust, as it tries to avoid escape characters in the Python representation of the loaded dictionary altogether. It comes with the caveat that the mangled sequences must not be present in the original string:

```py
import json

class ReplaceDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    
    def decode(self, s):
        assert "[s]" not in s and "[u]" not in s
        return super().decode(s.replace(r"\\", "[s]").replace(r"\u", "[u]"))

class ReplaceEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        
    def encode(self, o):
        return super().encode(o).replace("[u]", r"\u").replace("[s]", r"\\")

example=r"""
{
    "command": "python -m spacy download \\u en \u0026\u0026 python -m spacy download de \u0026\u0026 python main.py"
}
"""

json_example=json.loads(example, cls=ReplaceDecoder)
dumped = json.dumps(json_example, cls=ReplaceEncoder, indent=4)
assert(example[1:-1] == dumped)  # strip leading and trailing line break for assertion to work
```

Comment: Note that this will fail on input with two backslashes before a `u` (or any even number), where the `\u` sequence does not start a unicode escape (because the backslash was already escaped).

Comment: @user2357112 Well-spotted. I guess I fell into escape hell (https://xkcd.com/1638/). I will try to come up with a solution or otherwise add a corresponding warning. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: If you're going for regexes, you can search for an odd number of backslashes and a u, with a negative lookbehind asserting there's no backslash before the sequence starts. Also, unicode escapes can have uppercase hex digits. I think it'd look like `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}`

Comment: @user2357112 (1) Regarding the number of backslashes: I see a problem on the way back then (i.e. for the encoder), because how can I distinguish that the number of slashes resulted from my padding and had not been there before. (2) Regarding lower/uppercase: This should be handled by the IGNORECASE flag (also, the "U" can be uppercase as well)

Comment: Additionally, this will break for characters outside the BMP. JSON uses surrogate pairs to escape characters for python's \UNNNNNNNN.

Comment: @Andj Why would this break for characters outside plane 0?

Comment: In any case, I guess, at this point, I will give up.

Comment: @simon different forms of escaping between python and json

Comment: @simon for example  .
In Python, you'd use C-style escape: \U0001E900, while in JSON you'd escape it as \ud83a\udd00.

Comment: @Andj I see, thanks a lot. To be honest, I was not aware what kind of hornet's nest I was stirring up here

Comment: @simon it isn't so much that you were stirring up a hornets' nest, its more that the question wants python and JSON to behave differently from the way they do.

Comment: I think the 2nd version is reasonable: if you pick a replacement that is convoluted enough (more than [s]), then the probability to encounter such a substring is likely zero (in particular, the OP should be able to pick one that guarantees it)